# Row is not being Updated in Database Using GridView

Tags: c#, gridview, webforms

I am attempting an Update of my database via grid view image button. However, the changes are not being updated. All other operations are working namely Delete, Add New, Cancel. Below is my code for the GridView and C# code behind. Where did I go wrong?

GridView Declaration

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gvFarmer" runat="server"
        BackColor="White" BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="5" style="margin-right: 58px" DataKeyNames="Farmer_Id"
        CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Height="166px" Width="692px" ShowFooter="true" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" 

        OnRowCommand="gvFarmer_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="gvFarmer_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvFarmer_RowCancelingEdit" OnRowUpdating="gvFarmer_RowUpdating" 
        OnRowDeleting="gvFarmer_RowDeleting">
```

Buttons Column

```
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.jpg" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit Row" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>
                     <asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.jpg" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/Images/Save.jpg" runat="server" CommandName="Save" ToolTip="Save" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>
                     <asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/Images/Cancel.jpg" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/Images/Add New.jpg" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" ToolTip="Add New" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>

                </FooterTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Update Function Below

```
 protected void gvFarmer_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr))
            {
                con.Open();

                string InsertQuery = "UPDATE Farmer SET FirstName = @FirstName, LastName = @LastName, DOB = @DOB, Address = @Address, Gender = @Gender WHERE Farmer_Id = @Farmer_Id";
                //parametrized variables are used to prevent sql injection

                SqlCommand insert = new SqlCommand(InsertQuery, con);

                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Farmer_Id", Convert.ToInt32(gvFarmer.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString().Trim()));
                //get the info from textbox, trim spaces and store it in appropirate fields in the database.

                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", (gvFarmer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFarmerFirstName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", (gvFarmer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFarmerLastName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", (gvFarmer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFarmerDOB") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", (gvFarmer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFarmerAddress") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

                insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", (gvFarmer.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFarmerGender") as TextBox).Text.Trim());

                insert.ExecuteNonQuery(); //function executes the insert query

                gvFarmer.EditIndex =1;
                PopulateGridView(); //function is called to show updated view.

                lblSuccess.Text = "Record Updated!";
                lb1Error.Text = "";
            }//using block ends here

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            lblSuccess.Text = "";
            lb1Error.Text = ex.Message;
        }//end of try catch
    }//end of row updating function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **Update** for the command name on the save button

```
<asp:ImageButton  ImageUrl="~/Images/Save.jpg" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Save" Height="20px" Width="20px"/>
```